# Native X11 display not =:0.0

Tags: ubuntu, display, gnome, xorg

I am using Ubuntu Gnome 15.10 with Gnome Shell 3.16. Recently I noticed that my X11 is not running on `:0.0` but on `:1`. I thought the native display -the monitor of my laptop- should always be `:0.0`. Has anyone encountered such a thing? Is this normal, like a feature or something, or my display is somehow hijacked by something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is **nothing** that would require the "native display" to be `:0`. That's merely the first display number that is *usually* free when Xorg starts – but there are various reasons why it wouldn't be:

- When you use a display manager, it also launches the graphical login screen on the first available socket. Until now, most display managers would *reuse* the same X display for your own desktop, so if the login screen was at `:0`, your own programs would also use `:0`.

  But nothing requires that either. In fact, GNOME's GDM from 3.16 onwards always starts a *new* X display, leaving the login screen still running at the old one. It does so primarily to simplify the logic – Wayland-based sessions always start on a separate tty, so GDM now handles X11 sessions the same way.
- Most display managers, including GDM of course, also support user switching – so if two people log in to the same system, one would get `:0` and the other would get `:1`, even though both use the same "native" monitor & keyboard.

  (Well, `:1` and `:2` now, if you account for the new GDM behavior.) Same if you manually run `startx` on several tty's – one will be `:0`, one will be `:1`, one will be `:2`, and so on.
- It's also possible that Xorg was started at `:0` once, but crashed and left a stale socket at `/tmp/.X11-unix/X0`, making the display manager think `:0` was still in use.

The optional `.0` suffix indicates a *screen* in the old, pre-Xrandr multi-monitor mechanism. It's mostly meaningless these days.

---

In fact a similar situation exists in Windows, with Terminal Services being the rough equivalent of X11. Up until Windows XP, the first user would get session 0, and many services assumed they could show graphical interfaces there, despite being *services* and technically outside any session.

Besides being [insecure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shatter_attack), this also caused problems with User Switching and Remote Desktop, with some programs being outright unusable on sessions other than 0. Eventually it got so bad that Windows Vista started [reserving session 0](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2007/04/27/application-compatibility-session-0-isolation/) for services, and user logins now start at 1.

There is my hope that most X11 display managers will do so as well, just to break things which assume `DISPLAY=":0"`.